# Unable to Run Multiple Node Child Processes without Choking on DigitalOcean

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, digital-ocean, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I've been struggling to run multiple instances of Puppeteer on DigitalOcean for quite some time with little luck. I'm able to run ~5 concurrently using tools like [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster), but for some reason the whole thing just chokes with little helpful messaging. So, I switched to spawning ~5 child processes without any additional library -- just Puppeteer itself. Same issue. Chokes with no helpful errors.

I'm able to run all of these jobs just fine locally, but after I deploy, I hit these walls. So, my hunch is that it's a resource/performance issue, but I can't say for sure.

I'm running a droplet with 1GB and 3CPUs on Digital Ocean.

Basically, I'm just looking for ways to start troubleshooting something like this. is there a way I can know for sure that I'm hitting resource walls? I've tried pm2 and the DO dashboard graphs, but I feel like those are all leaving a lot of information out, or else I'm missing something else altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Author of `puppeteer-cluster` here. You are right, 1 GB of memory is likely not enough for running 5 browser windows (or tabs) in addition to your operating system and maybe even other background tasks.

Here is a list of resources you should check:

- **Memory**: Use a tool like [`htop`](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/) to check your memory usage while your application is running.
- **CPU**: Again, you can use `htop` for that, 3 vCPUs should be more than enough for 5 windows.
- **Disk space**: Use a tool like `df` to check if there is enough space on the disk. I know of multiple cases in which there was not enough space on the disk (like some old kernels filling the disk), and Chrome needs at least *some* space to run.
- **Network throughput**: Rarely the problem, but sometimes the network just does not have the bandwidth to support many open browser. Use a tool like `nload` to check the network throughput.

To use `htop` or `nload`, you start your script in the background (`node script.js &`) or use a terminal multiplexer (like [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki)). Resource problems should then be easy to spot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those out!

Comment: Your `htop` recommendation helped resolve the issue! Amazing, helpful tool. Found out that CPU usage was the main thing I was underestimating. I resized my droplet accordingly and now things are running very reliably. Thanks again for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're running out of memory, 5 puppeteer processes are a lot for a 1GB VM.

You can run

```
grep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages
```

to confirm that the OOM killer terminated your processes.