# puppeteer-cluster: Setting a timeout on individual execution tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer-cluster

I'm trying to get individual tasks to throw a time-out during stress testing to see what my calling program will do. However, my cluster keeps tasks fresh indefinitely. It appears to queue all my `cluster.execute` calls which then are kept in memory and return their results to listeners that have long since disconnected.

The docs state:

`timeout <number> Specify a timeout for all tasks. Defaults to 30000 (30 seconds).`

My cluster launch configuration:

```
const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
    maxConcurrency: 1,
    timeout: 1000 //milliseconds
});
```

I'm calling the queuing mechanism using:

```
const pdf = await cluster.execute(html, makePdf);
```

Where makePdf is an `async` function that expects a HTML string, fills a page with it and prints a PDF using the default `puppeteer`.

```
const makePdf = async ({ page, data: html, worker }) => {
    await page.setContent(html);
    let pdf = await page.pdf({});
    console.log('worker ' + worker.id + ' task ' + count);
    return pdf;
};
```

I sort of expected the queue to start emptying itself until it found a task that didn't exceed its timeout value. I've tried setting the `timeout` to 1 ms but this doesn't trigger a timeout either. I've tried moving this code to a `cluster.task` as described in the examples to see if that would trigger the setting, but no such luck. How do I get already queued requests to time out? Does this even work if I'm not scraping websites or connecting to anything?

I'm considering to pass a timestamp along with my tasks so it can skip doing anything for requests that have expired on the calling side, but I'd rather use built-in options wherever possible.

EDIT:

Thanks to Thomas's clarification I've decided to build this little optimization to prevent tasks where the listeners are long gone from executing.

Swap the content of `data` from just html with a json that has both the url and timestamp:

```
let timestamp = new Date();
await cluster.execute({html, timestamp});
```

Ignore any queued task where the listener has timed out:

```
const makePdf = async ({ page, data: { html, timestamp }, worker }) => {
    let time_since_call = (new Date() - timestamp);
    if (time_since_call < timeout_ms) {
        await page.setContent(html);
        let pdf = await page.pdf({});
        return pdf;
    } 
};
```

Comment: FYI: I added an [issue](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/issues/189) for your use case, but don't expect it to be implemented anytime soon please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding what `timeout` does. The `timeout` option is the timeout for the task, meaning that the job itself (after leaving the queue) cannot take longer than the specified timeout. The option does not cancel a queued job that is still in the queue.

**Example:**

```js
const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    // ...
    maxConcurrency: 1,
    timeout: 1000 // one second
});
// ...
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    cluster.queue('...');
}
```

This code adds 10 jobs and runs them sequentially (as `maxConcurrency` is `1`). There is no different between `queue` and `execute` here (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57361073/5627599) for more information on this topic). So what happens is the following:

- First job starts running
- First job is interrupted after one second
- Second job starts running
- Second job is interrupted  after one second
- ...

The use case you are describing is currently not supported by the library (btw, disclaimer: I'm the author), but as you proposed, you could add a timestamp to the object you are queuing and cancel the job right away if it is too far in the past.